# facebook-c#-sdk for windows phone mango 7.1, log-in fail

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk, windows-phone-7.1

I have The following problem:

I use facebook-c#-sdk for windows phone 7.1(mango version), taken from here:
http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/releases/view/76445 with the samples too,

for compatibility question, I've recompiled  the samples project situated inside the folder called `"FacebookCSharpSDK\Samples\CS-WP7"` for mango, after opening the application, I logged-in on the facebook form login and immediately after coming out a, maybe, error message.Here is  the screenshot of the problem: http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/6276/wp7error.png

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sounds like the sample code is wrong.  Have you tried writting your own software application and making its not a simple autentication problem?

Comment: yes, i wrote my own code for a simple login screen to facebook, but the problem is equal to the main code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, i've discovered a bug about the touch device in the facebook-sdk

after the code: `loginParameters["response_type"] = "code";`type in a new line this code:`loginParameters["display"]="wap";`